# C++ : what is this operator ^?

Tags: c++

int main()
{

```
std::string original = "Hello world";
std::string decrypted;
std::string encrypted;
char key = 'x';

cout << "Original string: " << original << endl << endl;

for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++)
{
    encrypted += original[i] ^ ((int)key + i) % 20;
}

cout << "Encrypted string: " << encrypted << endl << endl;

cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

I found this encryption program on youtube and i don't know what this line of code does-->encrypted += original[i] ^ ((int)key + i) % 20; . What is this ^ operator and what does it do exactly?I thought it was only used for raising a number to a power.Also when i change this line to encrypted = encrypted + original[i] ^ ((int)key + i) % 20; i get error "no match for operator in std::operator" , why is that?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the XOR function.

Comment: Google "C++ operators" and you'd find your answer. Questions here need to have been researched before their posted.

Comment: Though ^ itself would be hard to search for, @meagar's Google-fu is good.

Comment: I'm so torn on these questions. On one hand they can be answered in a second with google, but they get you points so easily!

Comment: @PaulDraper No, I mean literally search for ["C++ operators"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c%2B%2B+operators). You get *all* of them, in [nice little lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), that tell you exactly what each one does, usually with links to more details.

Comment: @meagar, right. My point was is that your way would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, `^` is the exclusive or, or XOR function. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Comment: Nice to see at least one person isn't trying to rep-farm

Answer (score 0):

This is the [XOR function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). It's commonly used in hashing methods for obtaining unique values based on the properties of an object.